# How to embed css codes in erb folder

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

Here are the original codes :

```
 <img src="images/title3.gif"  style=" display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto "></img>
```

Now  I make it to :

```
    <%= image_tag("title3.gif", ) %>
```

I don't want to put on the stylesheets folders .Can I do it ?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the question is. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Iceman I want to write the `style ` content with the `image_tag`

Comment: Adding style attributes to HTML tags is IMHO a code smell. Why don't you add the styles to a CSS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option `style`:

```
image_tag("title3.gif", style: "display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;")
```

Comment: @Vito read the documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag